# Multiple Tracking Events on a Single Button

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter, google-analytics, facebook-pixel

I have a client who needs multiple tracking events fired on a single button press. They are tracking all page visits using Facebook Pixel, Google Analytics and Twitter.

Their single Call to Action button also, apparently, needs all three trackings applied to it.

The site is built in WordPress using a framework called Elementor.

I have the page tracking implemented, no problem, but how on earth do I apply multiple event trackers on a single button-click?  I'm assuming I need to somehow trick that button into firing 3 times...

Normally this is where I'd paste in my HTML, CSS, JS telling you what I've tried but I haven't tried anything - I'm totally stumped on how to even begin this.

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE delegate media tag management to a dedicated tool. It is such a bad idea to put media tags in the site source code. Tag Management Systems have been a strong industry trend since 2012!

I would suggest [Google Tag Manager](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6102821?hl=en) since it is free, has a rich feature set, well described and rock solid.

You'll find plugins to integrate GTM with Wordpress, like https://gtm4wp.com

Next, you use Auto-event tracking to define a Trigger on Button click.
And bind each tag with that Trigger.

See 
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679320?hl=en

https://wiki.base22.com/btg/auto-events-trigger-google-tag-manager-169522561.html